Is there a way to increase a cleric's odds of success for Divine Intervention other than reaching level 20?
I'm playing as a fairy cleric, and my DM uses a houserule that Divine Intervention only has a 1/1000000 chance to succeed, and I feel like this is a bit low. Is there a magic item or spell (other than the automatic success gained at 20th level) that can increase my odds of success, or even guarantee it as a one-time thing?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

From the sound of some of your questions, your DM sounds... Different. If this is true, I would be really reconsidering playing with this DM.

I play different campaigns sometimes, so most of my questions aren't about this dm

Then maybe you have a few bad DMs. Or at least new DMs who don't understand certain things, in which case they are better off not making changes to rules as written until they have the experience to understand what they change and why. This is just a straight up nerf of a flavourful ability that isn't even all that powerful for seemingly no reason.

The odds improve with each level gained.
This class feature becomes available at level 10.  The probability of success works out to (cleric level)/100:

Imploring your deity’s aid requires you to use your action. Describe the assistance you seek, and roll percentile dice. If you roll a number equal to or lower than your cleric level, your deity intervenes.

With each cleric level from 10 to 19, the odds improve a little bit, until 20, where it succeeds automatically.
However, if your DM is using a house rule or homebrew version of the feature, you’ll have to ask them how it works and how its chances can be improved, because we can’t answer that.

Repeat your prayers
At 10th level, for instance, your odds of succeeding at divine intervention is 1 out of 10.  Not great odds if you need your god's aid right this second.
However, if it is something that can wait, you can repeat your request for aid the next day, and the day after, and the day after.  Eventually, you'll hit that 10%, but it may take a few days.
As a player, it would be pretty smart to discuss with the DM how divine intervention works in their game.  Even if your request is successful, "[t]he DM chooses the nature of the intervention".

In our game it's 1/1000000, hence why I was wondering about increasing the odds with magic items and spells

3d100 all have to land 100 in our game unless you're level 20

@Tasi Homebrew rules require homebrew solutions.

Homebrew is your DM's territory...
This 1/1,000,000 chance for success is not an official rule, and is instead something your DM designed specifically for your group, or for your campaign. As such, unfortunately, we cannot use the Rules As Written to find the insight you're looking for.
... but I wouldn't get my hopes up
If your DM gave your Divine Intervention such a low chance of success, it could be an indirect or softer way of removing it from their game.
After all, the chance of rolling a literal one-in-a-million in a standard game session with multiple players is so negligeable it seems unlikely anyone would want to spend their time trying.
Maybe they're scared a lucky roll would break their scenario or the balance between characters? Maybe they just don't want to deal with the implications of it.
Ask your DM
Your DM is the one who created this special rule, so they're the one who can answer best on how to play with it and change the odds.
They're also the one that can answer whether or not this was their way of "removing" it from the game, and explain why they did so.
